# asp.net textbox double (0,00) value validation

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, rangevalidator

I have a problem about validation controls. I have a textbox and I want to get amount value from this control. I use `RegularExpressionValidator` with this regex

```
^(\d+([\,]\d*)?)|(\d*([\,]\d+))$
```

and also I add `requiredfieldvalidator`. It is ok but I need one more control because I set the default text value `0,00` and I don't want to be able to pass with `0,00` it must be `>0,00`.

What can I do?

`RangeValidator` is useless in this situation because `0,00-x,xx` not acceptable for me. Please help.

Comment: _0,00-x,xx not acceptable for me?_ Its not clear what you want to say here. Is 0,01 acceptable?

Comment: yes, initial value of textbox is 0,00 and i dont accept 0,00 it must be different and also bigger than 0,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
^(?!0+(,0+)?$)((\d*,)?\d+)$
```

---

If you want only 2 digits after `,`, you can do this

```
^(?!0+(,0+)?$)(\d+(,\d{2})?)$
```

Comment: yes it is work for me thank you bro. But now i realize that i can enter value like this 01,00 can we block this with regex? and what about after "," only two digit? i know i can do this operations on code behind but i wonder can i do these operations with regex?

Comment: thanx it is enough for me bro